# How to pass a hash and a scalar to a Perl subroutine?

Tags: perl

I'm doing this:

```
foo(('x' => 'y'), 'bar');

use strict;

sub foo {
  my ($hash, $s) = @_;
  my %e = %$hash;
  print %e{'x'};
  print $s;
}
```

I'm getting:

```
Can't use string ("x") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at a.pl line 7.
```

What is the right way to pass a hash and a scalar to a subroutine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`('x' => 'y')` isn't a "hash", it's a list with two elements, and the parentheses don't even matter. What you're calling is the same as `foo('x', 'y', 'bar')`.

If you want to pass a hashref as the first argument, you can use the anonymous hash reference constructor: `foo({ x => 'y' }, 'bar')`.

Side note: `print %e{'x'}` should be `print $e{'x'}`. Or more simply, you can use the `->{}` operator to dereference and access at the same time: `print $hash->{'x'}`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got an answer pointing you to references, and you've accepted that - which is great.

But I just wanted to add that the easiest fix is to just swap the order of the parameters and make one tiny change to the subroutine.

```
foo('bar', ('x' => 'y'), 'bar');

sub foo {
  # NOTE: %hash, not $hash
  my ($s, %hash) = @_;
  # And there's no need for %e now
  print $hash{'x'};
  print $s;
}
```